# Sum of n I.I.D Uniform Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, uniform-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,....,X_n   \stackrel{i.i.d}{\sim}$ U($-0.5$,$0.5$) and let

T= $X_1+X_2+X_3+....+X_n$.

Suppose $n=100$, Then $P(T^2>25)$ is?

How do I solve such problem? I found out the sum of two and three i.i.d uniform random variables using convolution theorem, but it became more complicated after that. I know that this could be solved using property of i.i.d rv's but could not figure out how. Please help.

Comment: Please do not [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4262160/321264) your posts. Edit them instead.